# Convert jquery plugin into directive angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I'm trying to convert jQuery plugin into directive. Here is the library: [Github](https://github.com/mousavian/bootstrap-jalali-datepicker).

In the documentation there is an option :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepickerbtn").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#datepicker").focus();
        })
    });
```

Directive I've created :

```
app.directive('dateP', function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
            $(element).datepicker(scope.$eval(attr.dateP));
            console.log('hey');
            ngModel.$setViewValue(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

but it's not working , any help would be appreciate it .

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHQDDdagJbAaurqvgg69?p=preview) .

I've read this : https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you written `ng-mode` instead of `ng-model` and directive you should define date-picker options not the `scope.$eval(attr.dateP)` which is totally wrong. Inside [**datepicker**](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/) you need to provide their options in `json` format like here we mentioned option as `{ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' })`

**HTML**

```
<input date-p id="datepicker1" class="input-small" type="text" ng-model="dt">
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('dateP', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      element.datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Update**

For show `datepicker` on button click you need to do add below method inside your controller.

**Controller**

```
$scope.showDatepicker =  function(){
  angular.element('#datepicker1btn').datepicker('show');
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lFGbXG9A14X98evE85M0?p=preview)

Thanks.

Comment: @sani checked and plunkr and answer too

Comment: awsome , can i ask u one more thing ? how did you know that we should add this ;   link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      element.datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      });

Comment: or angular.element('#datepicker1btn').datepicker('show');

Comment: because its option for `datepicker ` that we are providing option in json like `{ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }` look at this then only it will bind to that element .

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/