# AngularJS: How to execute jquery inside directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a tree structure which uses jQuery. I had to use the same jQuery in my Angular application. I was able to create the tree structure with angularjs using directives, but i was not able to execute the jQuery. Please check my code  http://plnkr.co/edit/JhG4lEiOX6uXYCyHZhOQ?p=preview and let me know what can i do to fix the issue. Below is the jQuery code that need to be executed.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tree").treeview({
      collapsed: false,
      animated: "medium",
      control: "#sidetreecontrol",
      persist: "location"
    });

    $thumbs = $('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
      $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
    });
})
```

Comment: you should avoid using jquery + angular, angular should fit your requirements somehow...

Comment: @Julo0sS I SO disagree..

Comment: @Julo0sS that is not completely true. if you go at docs of angular.element, you can find that has basic implementation of jquery there. which would fail if you use some jquery library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert jquery plugin into directive angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630191/convert-jquery-plugin-into-directive-angular)

Comment: @Jai This is not completely false... ^^ :P

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own directive to wrap your jQuery plugin

http://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.sliderValue = 50;
}]);
app.directive('jqSlider', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'model': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $(elem).treeview({
       collapsed: false,
       animated: "medium",
       control: "#sidetreecontrol",
       persist: "location"
     });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: i got error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=hierarchy&p1=%20(module:%20myApp)&p2=treeAttr&p3=&p4=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p5=%3Cul%20tree-attr%3D%22%22%20hierarchy%3D%22components%22%3E

Comment: I have updated my plunker, but i'm not able to understand how to use the following code 
$thumbs = $('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
  $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
});

Answer (score 0):

It is true that is not recommended to use jQuery (a lot) when using AngularJS, but if you really need to here is a [good example](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html).

Also can check this related [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

Updating my jQuery library solved the issue.